# to find the location of roots of an equation

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

The question is

> prove that 
>   $\dfrac {e^\pi}{x-\pi} + \dfrac {\pi^e}{x-e} + \dfrac {e^e+\pi^\pi}{x-e -\pi} = 0 $ . has one real root in $(e,\pi)$ and other $(\pi,\pi+e)$.

I tried this question hard but I couldn't find any easy way to solve the question , since simplifying these fraction doesn't really help , I also tried to manipulate the equation but I couldn't succeed .Any help , hint , solution would be really appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: I think the easiest thing to see is if $e < x < \pi$ then $\frac {e^\pi}{x -\pi}$ is negative.  $\frac {\pi^e}{x-e}$ is positive.  And $\frac {e^e+\pi^\pi}{x-\pi-e}$ is negative.  The question are there values where the positive terms become large compared to the negative so the whole thing is positive and are there values where the negative term overpower and the whole thing is negative. That would mean here is some term in between where to whole thing is $0$. Thing is you don't have to *find* these values just to know they exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\dfrac {e^\pi}{x-\pi} + \dfrac {\pi^e}{x-e} + \dfrac {e^e+\pi^\pi}{x-e -\pi}.$

Thus, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow e^+}f(x)=+\infty$$ and 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi^-}f(x)=-\infty.$$
But $f$ is continuous on $(e,\pi)$, which says that there is a root of the equation on $(e,\pi)$.

By the same way we can obtain that there is a root on $(\pi,e+\pi).$

But, $f(x)=0$ is a quadratic equation...

Another way.

Rewrite our equation in the form $g(x)=0$, where 
$$g(x)=e^{\pi}(x-e)(x-e-\pi)+\pi^e(x-\pi)(x-e-\pi)+(e^{\pi}+\pi^{\pi})(x-e)(x-\pi).$$

Now, check $g(e),$ $g(\pi)$ and $g(e+\pi).$

Easy to see that $g(e)>0$, $g(\pi)<0$ and $g(e+\pi)>0$.

Comment: can you do it by simple algebra not using calculus

Comment: @Akshaj Bansal Yes, of course. Just see it as a quadratic function.

Comment: can you please elaborate how it is a quadratic function and how can we prove the location of roots

Comment: @Akshaj Bansa I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wolfy, there are roots at about
2.9 and 4.3.

Looking at the equation informally,
if $x$ is just above $e$ it is positive,
if $x$ us just below $\pi$ it us negative,
if $x$ is just above $\pi$ it is positive,
and for large $x$ it is negative.

The numerators do not matter
except for their signs.